# jQuery Slide Left Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four `div`'s or `td`'s and what I am trying to do is if I click on any one, then all of them slide left, the remaining three should disappear, and the one I clicked should remain.

I also want a neat animation effect.

I have tried this but it gives some error for style:

```
//xControl is a link inside the td
$(xControl).parent().siblings().each(function fn() {
    setTimeout(function fn() {
        $(this).animate({ width: 'toggle' });
    }, 800);
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
```

This doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your HTML?  How about a jsFiddle?  What is the exact error message?

Comment: I am sorry! I'll put all that info.. I am actually trying to edit a purchased template.. so the styling is complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, might start you out:
http://jsfiddle.net/M8scf/2/

```
.item
{ 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;            
    background:lime;
    cursor:pointer;        
}

<div class="con">
    <div class="item">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="item">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="item">DIV 3</div>
    <div class="item">DIV 4</div>
</div>

$(".con .item").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().hide("slow");    
});​
```

Comment: Questions and answers should be [fully self-contained](http://sscce.org).  Otherwise, this is all useless whenever the links go dead.

Comment: How's that?  Maybe stackoverflow can approach jsfiddle to talk about integration as almost every web related question here gets answered by a jsfiddle example.  If questions don't include a jsfiddle example the first thing contributors ask for is a jsfiddle.  You have a kratillion posts to moderate if your concerned about jsfiddle links without answer description text.

Comment: I don't recall asking you not to use a jsFiddle.  Just don't use it alone and all by itself.  This issue is discussed at length at the [meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will abide by the preferred use of jsfiddle.

Comment: By your last comment, I'm still not sure you understand that this is not about using jsFiddle... it's about using it all by itself.  By the way, I use a jsFiddle within nearly every answer I post... along with the code and any applicable explanations.  I even asked the OP to post one in my comment above.

Comment: I get it.  Link to jsFiddle for demos, include pertinent code from those jsfiddle demos in the stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(xControl).on("click", function(){
    var thisDiv = $(this);
    var sibs = thisDiv.siblings();
    sibs.animate({'left':'-=150'},{queue:false,complete:function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':0});
        }
    });
    thisDiv.animate({'left':'-=150'},{queue:false});
});
```

This is more or less how I would do it.  You can do whatever animations you want in there besides a slide and fade.  You can use the jquery-ui built in functions, but I like animate personally for the more customizable animations.

Here's my fiddle to show what it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/AXkxQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$(xControl).parent().siblings().each(function fn() {
setTimeout(function fn() {
    $(this).animate({ left: '-=500px' });
}, 800);
```

});

you have to make sure you have in your css the possition set as relative `xControl{position: relative;}`

Comment: I don't think `this` inside `$(this)` is `window`, not an element any more.